# Set the value of a ItemTemplate label on ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, label, itemtemplate

I have a Datagrid with a TemplateColumn. In that column I have 2 Labels containing some data.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgData" runat="server" Width="658px" CellPadding="2" PageSize="2" DataKeyField="ID"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" BorderColor="AliceBlue" OnItemDataBound="dgData_ItemDataBound">
  <SelectedItemStyle ForeColor="HighlightText" BackColor="Highlight"></SelectedItemStyle>
  <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke"></AlternatingItemStyle>
  <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" BackColor="AliceBlue"></HeaderStyle>
  <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" BackColor="AliceBlue"></FooterStyle>
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Term 1" ItemStyle-Wrap="True">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:label BorderStyle=None Visible='<%# ReverseBool(Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsCompleteOrNot"))) %>'   runat="server" ID="edit_Score" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Score" ) %>'>
        </asp:label>
        <asp:label BorderStyle=None Text='<%# GetCompleteIncomplete(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Score"))) %>' Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.IsCompleteOrNot") %>' id="txtIsComplete" runat="server">
        </asp:label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
  </Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

I see this when it runs: 
[image: There is the Name and the Value is 0]
If the Text property is 0, I want to set the Text to an empty value instead of showing the '0'.

So far, I've tried the following on ItemDataBound event:

```
if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
              (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
            {
                var ModuleName = e.Item.Cells[1].Text;
                Label edit_Score = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("edit_Score"); // This gets the Label's values 
                Label txtIsComplete = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("txtIsComplete");
  if (edit_Score.Text == "0" ) 
            {
                // I initially tried setting the text to "" but that didn't work.
                // Setting it to null doesn't seem to work either.
                edit_Score.Text = null;

                txtIsComplete.Text = null;

                //edit_Score2.Visible = false;
            }
```

What is the proper way to blank the Text property of this Label control within a TemplateColumn using the ItemDataBound event?

Comment: you can use `string.Empty` instead of `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately  that didn't work its till showing 0s

Comment: Its not answer. Its just a comment.

Comment: Yeah you are right I am still getting used to stuff on Stack overflow :D thanks any ways.